# Does useCallback have a semantic guarantee?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The React documentation says the following about `useMemo`

> You may rely on useMemo as a performance optimization, not as a
> semantic guarantee. In the future, React may choose to “forget” some
> previously memoized values and recalculate them on next render, e.g.
> to free memory for offscreen components. Write your code so that it
> still works without useMemo — and then add it to optimize performance.

For `useCallback` there is the following line:

> useCallback(fn, deps) is equivalent to useMemo(() => fn, deps).

The word "equivalent" is a bit fuzzy for me and I don't know if that also means that `useCallback` does not provide a semantic guarantee.

Comment: Future versions haven't been written yet, so I'd guess that it's still up in the air for `useCallback` too, unless they explicitly say otherwise somewhere

Comment: If your memoized function has side effects don't trust that react won't rerun it. Add a conditional check.

Comment: Actually every react hook (maybe except useState) should have a huge hint - "Do not use unless you know what you are doing" ;)

Comment: @kinduser That is an irrelevant and very juvenile comment to make.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`useMemo` is equal to `useCallback` if the return value of the `useMemo` was a function:

```
// The return value of `useMemo` is calculated every time deps change
useMemo(() => {
  return () => { // do some stuff }
}, [deps])

// The function block within `useCallback` is redefined every time deps change
useCallback(() => {
  // do some stuff
}, [deps])
```

I don't know the reason why they made separate hooks for this but I guess they are technically doing the same thing.

As for having a semantic guarantee, I'd say they might do the same thing with `useCallback` to "free some memory" but a function memory consumption is less significant than actual data.

Comment: Does this really answer the question about the semantic guarantee of useCallback? It seems likely that one reason for offering two very similar hooks is because useMemo is less future proof than other hooks. Callback functions might rely on that semantic guarantee. For example when you are using debounce / throttle.

Comment: Related: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/15278